# I can't select WSL under Configure Remote PHP Interpreter

Tags: phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the latest version of PhpStorm and WSL2. I have also followed all the steps here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html.

Unfortunately, I do not have the option to select WSL as shown in the picture. Can anyone help me how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html -- this looks like a more appropriate Help page for your question. So .. check that the corresponding **PHP WSL Support** plugin is enabled -- that's the first thing to look at. If it's already enabled (should be by default) then try the following: 1) disable it and rest art the IDE; 2) enable it again and restart the IDE; 3) See if WSL option will now appear. P.S. Restart the PC as well just in case...

Comment: @LazyOne It's so strange. I have activated the plugin and restarted the IDE, but it did nothing. Now I did it again and it worked. Thanks for the quick help.